# code does not run off @reboot tag

Tags: python, cron

Not sure where the issue is but my code doesnt run correcrtly when its in a cron.

This is in my cron.d:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot pi /home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/airpi/airpi.py  >> /home/pi/scripts/airpi/logs/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M`_airpi.txt 2>&1 &
```

Here is what I see in the logs when it runs:

```
['/home/pi/scripts/airpi', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
        raise NewConnectionError(
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x75759298>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Now when I run it manually using the same command I have in the cron as user `pi` it runs correctly:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/scripts/airpi $ /home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/airpi/airpi.py
['/home/pi/scripts/airpi', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
PM2.5 = 14.0
PM10 = 21.8
PM2.5 = 13.9
```

Here's the code: https://github.com/chowpay/airpi

Comment: What happens if you add a delay of 20-30 seconds?  Gut feel is that the task is running before networking is fully up. I do not think that setting the 'wait for networking' in raspi-config would help in this case.

Comment: I think you're right so I added a sleep But now I dont think my cron.d is working at all: `SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

@reboot sleep 60 && pi /home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/airpi/airpi.py  >> /home/pi/scripts/airpi/logs/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M`_airpi.txt 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andyroo is correct the issue I had was a delay in the network coming up before the script started to run. But I could not get the syntax right. Finally figured it out:

Here is the correct format to add sleep for cron.d:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

@reboot pi sleep 60 && /home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/airpi/airpi.p
```

If using crontab -e

```
@reboot sleep 60; /home/pi/scripts/airpi/venv38/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/airpi/airpi.py
```